# Get signal when tid status change

Tags: c, linux, signals, waitpid

There is a way to look when pid/tid status change with `waitpid` but this  is blocking function.

I want to monitor all threads in specific pid and get signal when one of them change and print the tid.

For now I open threads as count of threads in that process  and each 1 make `waitpid` on 1 tid and after that blocking function finish I print that tid that changed.

How can I get a signal that tid change so I can monitor all  tid's in 1 thread.

I didn't want to monitor all pid in system only specific pid/tid.

Those tids/pids are not children of my process.

Comment: Have you never wondered what the [`waitpid`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) `option` argument is used for?

Comment: You can set a signal handler for `SIGCHLD`.

Comment: And are you using actual *threads* or *processes*? While implemented similarly in Linux, they are still different things.

Comment: @Some programmer dude , Yes but I didn't found how can I get a signal when pid changed

Comment: @ShawnWhat do you mean please?

Comment: I mean that you can use `waitpid` to *poll* using the `WNOHANG` option flag.

Comment: Please clarify (preferably by showing us a [mcve] of what you're doing) if you're creating *threads* or *processes*. They need to be handled differently.

Answer (score 0):

You can call

```
int status;
pid_t waitpid(-1, &status, 0);
```

to wait for *any* child process change.
So you do not have to specify in advance, which pid to monitor, and can react on any status change. This way you do not need to start one thread for each pid.

As to the signal part of your question: A `SIGCHLD` is sent to your process when a child process exits. This signal is ignored by default, but you can install a custom signal handler for it, of course.

If you only want to reap specific pids, linux provides the option `WNOWAIT`, which only reports the state, but does not really reap the child process. Now you can check, if the pid is one of those you want to monitor, and if so, call `waitpid()` again without the option.

If the processes are not children, `waitpid()` cannot be used in general. One option is, to attach with `ptrace()` to these 40 processes to get signalled, if one of these processes exit. This might have unwanted side-effects, however.

Comment: I sorry , I edit the post, what I mean is to monitor all tid's status change in specific pid

Comment: @paramikoooo `waitpid()` does not work at all for non-child processes. There is one (a bit hacky) option however, see above.

Comment: @paramikoooo If you pass `-1` as the pid to wait for, you wait for all *child* processes, not "all" processes. And even with `SIGCHLD` you'll get signals for all child processes as well.

Comment: @Ctx , ok I using  `ptrace` to attach to each of that tid's, and then how can I get signal when one of them changed without blocking?

Comment: @paramikoooo Just install a SIGCHLD handler, that should be called on tracee exit

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Of course child processes, I presumed that this is clear...

Comment: @Ctx thank you so much  about all , so do I need to install a SIGCHLD handler  ,and then use `PTRACE_ATTACH` (without `waitpid ` ) to attach the tid and then I will get signal to handler function when the tid chaged? will I get the thread number to that handler ?

Comment: @paramikoooo Indeed I have not tested this with individual threads, but it _should_ work ,because _strace_ on threads works, too. If you install the signal handler with `sigaction()` and `SA_SIGINFO`, then you get a siginfo-structure containing the pid.

Comment: @Ctx The problem is that the question mentions *threads* not processes.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude As I said, it should work with threads (watching them with `ptrace()` for exit)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using POSIX threads, then you could use [`pthread_cleanup_push` and `pthread_cleanup_pop`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cleanup_push.3.html) to call a "cleanup" function when your thread is exiting.

This "cleanup" function could then send one of the user signals (`SIGUSR1` or `SIGUSR2`) to the process which then catches it and treats it as a signal about thread termination.

If you use [`sigqueue`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sigqueue.3.html) you can add the thread-id for the signal handler so it knows which thread just exited.

You can use [`pthread_sigmask`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_sigmask.3.html) to block the user signal in all threads, to make sure it's only delivered to the main process thread (or use [`pthread_sigqueue`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_sigqueue.3.html) to send to the main process thread specifically).