# Is sa_sigaction is thread safe?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, thread-safety

```
  struct sigaction action;

  action.sa_sigaction = ChildHandler; 
  sigfillset (&action.sa_mask);
  action.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO; 

  sigaction (SIGCHLD, &action, NULL);


void ChildHandler (int sig, siginfo_t *sip, void *notused)
{
int x= 7;
int y = 9;
int z = x + y ; 
int y=1;
}
```

function `ChildHandler` called when `SIGCHLD` is arrived.

How that implement? do I need to protect `ChildHandler` with lock?

Otherwise in the example if 2 signal will arivved in the same time , the code cala will be wrong

Comment: You *can't* receive two signals of the same type simultaneously, POSIX forbids it.

Comment: @Some programmer dude They not need to be in same time, they second signal only need to come before the first handle finish

Comment: "Simultaneously" here means "while signal handler is running". Some signals queue up (I think `SIGCHLD` does) while some signals will be dropped if they happen while a signal handler is already running.

Comment: The handler doesn't need to be reentrant, because you can block/hold signal delivery while the handler is running.  But, the handler necessarily runs in one of your threads, so it competes with all other running threads when it accesses global variables. Can you give some actual code? Then we'll be able  to give a better answer.

Comment: *the code cala will be wrong*  I'm not sure what you mean by that, but a signal handler can be run at any time, and can interrupt any processing, so if the example code you posted in your signal handler represents some process where the inputs change, you can't be assured that they're in a consistent state when your signal handler runs.  And you **CAN NOT** safely protect those variables with a lock because your signal handler can deadlock waiting for that lock if the signal interrupts a thread while it holds the lock.

Comment: @Andrew Henle So for my example , how can I protect this handler to be thread safe ?there is no way?

Comment: First of all, if you only want the main process thread to handle this signal, you need to block it in all other threads (I mentioned `pthread_sigmask` in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60204533/440558) to your [previous (and very related) question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60203706/440558)). Then just don't do anything that needs thread synchronization (no mutexes, no conditional variables, no semaphores, no atomics, etc.). Ultimately you just set a flag or increase a counter or similarly, and you will be okay.